# how to get mapped data from list item onclick from child to parent in react

Tags: reactjs, axios, onclick

Hey just learning react and I'm trying to get the data from the clicked item in the child component to the parent component. I can get a single value if I use "data-value(item.city)" but I'm trying to get the entire array and when I just do "data-value(item)" it gives me [object][object]. Not even sure if using data-value is the right approach.

Also as a bonus question I was wondering if there was a better way to write the multiple apis calls or if chaining them like that is acceptable, should I be using async/await?

Child Component

```
import React from "react";
import { Container, Card, ListGroup } from "react-bootstrap";

const WeatherPanel = (props) => {
    return (
        <div>
            <Container fluid>
                <Card style={{ width: "50%", boxShadow: "0  0  10px 2px lightgrey" }}>
                    <Card.Header> Favorite Location</Card.Header>
                    <ListGroup variant="flush">
                        <ListGroup.Item>
                            {props.data.map((item, index) => (
                                <ListGroup.Item key={item.id} data-value={item} onClick={props.handleClick}>
                                    <img src={`http://openweathermap.org/img/wn/${item.icon}@2x.png`} alt="Weather Icon" />
                                    {item.city}
                                </ListGroup.Item>
                            ))}
                        </ListGroup.Item>
                    </ListGroup>
                </Card>
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
};

export default WeatherPanel;
```

Parent Component

```
import "./App.css";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

import { Container } from "react-bootstrap";

import WeatherPanel from "./components/WeatherPanel/WeatherPanel.jsx";
import Header from "./components/Header/Header";

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const fetchData = () => {


            axios
                .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"Ottawa"}&appid=${key}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    setData((data) => [...data, { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, id: res.data.id }]);
                    return axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"Toronto"}&appid=${key}`);
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    setData((data) => [...data, { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, id: res.data.id }]);

                    return axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"Montreal"}&appid=${key}`);
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    setData((data) => [...data, { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, id: res.data.id }]);

                    return axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"Vancouver"}&appid=${key}`);
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    setData((data) => [...data, { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, id: res.data.id }]);
                    return axios.get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${"California"}&appid=${key}`);
                })
                .then((res) => {
                    setData((data) => [...data, { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, id: res.data.id }]);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);

    const handleClick = (event, index) => {
        console.log(event.target.dataset.value);
        //What do I need to do?
    };

    return (
        <div className="App">
            <Header />
            <Container>
                <WeatherPanel data={data} handleClick={handleClick} />
            </Container>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

data-value is a string attribute, convert item to string

```
<ListGroup.Item key={item.id} data-value={JSON.stringify(item)} />
```

I would call API using parallel approach

```
useEffect(() => {

        const fetchSingle = (city) => {
            return axios
                .get(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=${key}`)
                .then((res) => {
                    setData((data) => [...data, { description: res.data.weather[0].description, icon: res.data.weather[0].icon, temp: res.data.main.temp, city: res.data.name, id: res.data.id }]);
        }
        const fetchData = () => {
            const many = [
                fetchSingle("Ottawa"),
                fetchSingle("Toronto"),
                fetchSingle("Montreal"),
                fetchSingle("Vancouver")
            ]

             Promise.all(many).catch((err) => {
                 console.log(err);
             });
        };
        fetchData();
    }, []);
```

Comment: Thanks, this approach looks cleaner. Maybe I should have explained that I want to re-render the data in a new component, using data-value can I do this? I get a json object when I click and then I guess I send it to the new component through props but what would be the best way to render this data now. Do I have to push it into a new state array in new component?